# CS Code - Problema ao executar script pelo terminal

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Olá!
Estou começando agora a estudar programação, e estou seguindo umas video-aulas de um curso onlyne.

Nessem momento do curso, o professor está mostrando como usar o terminal do CS Code.
Mais especificamente, rodar o script com uma função, informando a variável no próprio terminal.
É um código bem simples. Mas de repente meu CS Code parou de executar o código no próprio terminal. Ao invéz disso, quando eu dou "Enter", ele abre o CMD do windows. Se o código pede algum input, ele fica com o CMD aberto esperando, e quando eu informo o valor, ele simplesmente fecha. Se não tiver nenhuma solicitação de dados no código, ele abre e fecha rapidamente o CMD, mas no CS Code não acontece nada. (imagem 1)

Esse erro está acontecendo agora, mas não estava assim antes. Eu executei algumas coisas no terminal no início do curso, e estava normal. De repente parou de funcionar (inclusive os scripts antigos salvos). Por isso eu acho que seria algum problema de configuração, e não do script em si.

Vou colocar algumas imagens pra explicar melhor.

Imagem do script (está exatamente igual ao do curso). Pode ver que no terminal ele não está retornando nada (deveria aparecer o "print" do script)
[Imagem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJNMC.png)

Agora, se eu insiro um "input" no lugar de informar diretamente a variável, ele abre o CMD do windows também:
[Imagem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bx18.png)

Acabei de começar a mexer no programa, mas acabei empacando nesse ponto. Não está executando, e não consigo seguir com o curso. Se alguém puder me ajudar :)

Comment: ao tentar iniciar o script como `./area_circulo_v10.py  1.2` não retorna nada pois python não tem esse tipo de inicialização. o modo esperado é `python area_circulo_v10.py  12`.. Sempre que utilizar o **input** e executar pelo vscode ele vai abrir o terminal **CMD** é a unica forma. Se esse foi sua questão..

Comment: Nas abas superiores do vscode tem uma opção chamada **Terminal** > **Novo Terminal**, algo assim. Não sei se no Windows segui as opções de sistema baseado em linux. Que é uma forma de entrada de dados **python area_circulo_v10.py  1.2**

Comment: Olá! Obrigado pelo comentário! Eu consegui rodar colocando "python" no início! Eu acabei de começar a aprender, e não tenho a mínima noção ainda kkk Obrigado!!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Usando o terminal do vscode, caso não saibas o comando do python experimente estes:

```
py area_do_circulo.py 2.1
py3 area_do_circulo.py 2.1
python area_do_circulo.py 2.1
python3 area_do_circulo.py 2.1
```

Comment: Obrigado! Eu usei o python no começo e funcionou. Acabei de começar a aprender, não tenho a mínima noção kkk tava empacado por conta disso, mas resolveu aqui. Valeu mesmo!!

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia Eric, você está tentando executar teu script no terminal utilizando a tecla tab?
Tenta ao invés de utilizar o terminal para executar teu script usar a tecla F5 (debug) que o vscode já vai executar pra vc,
Caso você queira executar o script via terminal, comece digitando py + nome do programa.

ex:
`py area_do_circulo.py`